# Insert created element at start of html tag using PHP DOM

Tags: php, dom, appendchild, setattribute, getelementsbytagname

I'm trying to insert an HTML `<base>` tag immediately after the opening `<head>` tag of a page using dom. I've tried using `appendChild` which just inserts it before the `</head>` which is no good.

Code im using:

```
$head = $dom->getElementsByTagName('head')->item(0);
$base = $dom->createElement('base');
$base->setAttribute('href', $url);
$head->parentNode->insertBefore($base, $head);
```

This inserts the `<base>` tag before the `<head>`, which is still no good!

Any ideas? Beer for the correct answer!

Comment: parentNode is necessary? i assume heads' parentnode is html.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$head = $dom->getElementsByTagName('head')->item(0);
$base = $dom->createElement('base');
$base->setAttribute('href',$url);

if ($head->hasChildNodes()) {
    $head->insertBefore($base,$head->firstChild);
} else {
    $head->appendChild($base);
}
```

If the `<head>` element already has children, it inserts the `<base>` element before `<head>`'s first child. If `<head>` has no children, it just appends it to `<head>`.